# CloudFlare Origin Certificate configure on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssl-certificate, ssrs-2012, cloudflare, reportserver

I am facing an issue with the Cloudflare Origin Certificate. I create the certificate (.pfx) using Cloudflare private key and pem. I have successfully configured this on IIS but when I am trying to configure this on SSRS (report Server) then it doesn't allow me to configure.

as per my observation, it is that Cloudflare is issuing a general Origin Certificate. It is not generated for a specific domain, but I am not sure.

[image]

Did anyone face the same issue earlier?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I've used CertifyWeb to create a free SSL using Let's encrypt.